# GUI-based IoC container?

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control

Is there an IoC container out there where the configuration is live and done through a diagram-like gui rather than through code or xml-like config?

I am thinking of something like [Simulink](http://www.mathworks.com/products/simulink/), where each of the box in the diagram would represent a C# object and the links would represent the dependency injection.

I see plenty of pretty cool use cases, but I can't find anything that even remotely looks like that.

Comment: Sounds like something you could build yourself quickly with Reflection. VS has something like this in the Object Test Bench window, but it's for instantiating classes as objects and testing methods rather than messing around with class composition and design patterns.

Comment: +1 This sounds like a fantastic idea, would be cool to see this kind of thing available.

Comment: Evaluated a lot of IoC but didn't saw any with GUI/Diagram support nor  3rd party addon's for something like this.

Comment: Why would this be interesting?

Comment: @MarkSeemann: Well it's the same kind of idea behind Simulink, Yahoo Pipes, Lighttable to a certain extent, excel object libraries. Component integration seems more natural when done in a 2D diagram than in code or in xml config files.

Comment: Here's where I must quote Anders Hejlsberg: "Sometimes a line of code says more than a thousand pictures."

Comment: MarkSeemann: quotes that start with "sometimes" aren't really useful

Comment: A much better question would be: Are there a container which can generate a dependency graph using all registered services. Using a tool to register everything isn't very interesting since it's the constructors that dictate the dependencies.